# VBA to Python for array and nested iteration

Tags: python, excel, vba, loops, nested-loops

I want to make this vba code into python, but i stuck in nested loop. Here is the vba code and result

**table equation**
[image]:

```
Sub iter_K()

num_HW = 4


For i = 1 To num_HW
    For k = 1 To 0.01 Step -0.01
        Range(Cells(1 + i, 5), Cells(1 + num_HW, 5)) = k
        'Cells(1 + i, 5) = k
        status_gap = Cells(1 + i, 10)
        If status_gap = 1 Then Exit For
    Next k
Next i


End Sub
```

Here is an explanation of the columns in the table:

- HW: Headwork number.
- QL: data.
- QA: The Final Quantity, indicating the remaining quantity in each
  iteration. QA is the sum of QL and QS from the previous iteration (QA
  = QL + QS).
- QD: data.
- K: The K factor used in each iteration. K ranges from 1 to 0.2 in
  steps of 0.01 in each iteration.
- QR: the minimum value between K * QD and QA, representing how much is
  taken by HW.
- QS: the difference between QA and QR (QS = QA - QR).
- K_real: (K_real = QR / QD).
- Gap_K: The difference between the K_real from the previous iteration and the current iteration. Gap_K indicates the change in K_real.
- Status_Gap: The Gap Status, showing whether Gap_K is less than or
  equal to 0.01. If Gap_K <= 0.01, then Status_Gap is 1; otherwise,
  Status_Gap is 0. Status_Gap indicates whether the iteration is
  approaching convergence.

Here is my python code but it doesn't return the same result with the vba script:

```
def calculate_water_flow(QL, QD, K):
    num_HW = len(QL)
    n = 1
    QA = []
    QR = []
    QS = []
    K_real = []
    Gap_K = []

    for i in range(0, num_HW):
        if i == 0:
            qa = QL[i]
        else:
            qa = QL[i] + (QS[i - 1] if i >= 1 else 0)
        QA.append(qa)

        qr = min(K * QD[i], qa)
        QR.append(qr)

        qs = qa - qr
        QS.append(qs)

        k_real = qr / QD[i]
        K_real.append(k_real)

    Gap_K = [0] + [K_real[i] - K_real[i - 1] for i in range(1, num_HW)]

    return QA, QR, QS, K_real, Gap_K

def print_results(QA, QR, QS, K_real, Gap_K, iterations):
    num_HW = len(QA)

    print("HW\tQL\tQA\tQD\tK\tQR\tQS\tK_real\tGap_K\tStatus_Gap")
    for i in range(num_HW):
        status_gap = 1 if Gap_K[i] <= 0.01 else 0
        print(f"{i + 1}\t{QL[i]}\t{QA[i]:.2f}\t{QD[i]}\t{K:.2f}\t{QR[i]:.2f}\t{QS[i]:.2f}\t{K_real[i]:.2%}\t{Gap_K[i]:.2%}\t{status_gap}")
    
    print(f"Total iterations: {iterations}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QL = [50, 30, 80, 60]
    QD = [100, 150, 120, 80]
    K = 1  
    iteration = 0  

    QA, QR, QS, K_real, Gap_K = calculate_water_flow(QL, QD, K)
    while any(gap > 0.01 for gap in Gap_K):
        iteration += 1
        K -= 0.01
        if K < 0.01:
            K = 0.01
        QA, QR, QS, K_real, Gap_K = calculate_water_flow(QL, QD, K)
    
    print_results(QA, QR, QS, K_real, Gap_K, iteration)
```

Comment: OT: Please note that writing in all upper-case, even in titles, is considered to be shouting. And it's very rude to shout at the people you want to help you.

Comment: okay i am sorry guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

- VBA and Python code have different logic.

Let's compare the iteration on `HW=1`.

VBA code validate if Gap_K<0.01 (formula in J2) for current row (row# is 2).

```vb
            status_gap = Cells(1 + i, 10)
            If status_gap = 1 Then
                Exit For
            End If
```

Py code tries to validate `Item of Gap_K list<0.01`, there are 4 items in `Gap_K` list.

```py
while any(gap > 0.01 for gap in Gap_K)
```